# divide not rectangle plot into subplots within spatstat package in R

Tags: r, plot, subplot, spatstat

I have data that contains information about sub-plots with different numbers and their corresponding species types (more than 3 species within each subplot). Every species have X & Y coordinates.

```
> df
  subplot      species      X       Y
1       1     Apiaceae 268675 4487472
2       1  Ceyperaceae 268672 4487470
3       1     Vitaceae 268669 4487469
4       2  Ceyperaceae 268665 4487466
5       2     Apiaceae 268662 4487453
6       2 Magnoliaceae 268664 4487453
7       3 Magnoliaceae 268664 4487453
8       3     Apiaceae 268664 4487456
9       3     Vitaceae 268664 4487458
```

with these data, I have created ppp for the points of each subplot within a window of general plot (big).

```
 grp <- factor(data$subplot)
 win <- ripras(data$X, data$Y)
 p.p <- ppp(data$X, data$Y, window = window, marks = grp)
```

Now I want to divide a plot into equal 3 x 3 sub-plots because there are 9 subplots. The genetal plot is not rectangular looks similar to rombo shape when I plot.

I could use quadrats() funcion as below but it has divided my plot into unequal subplots. Some are quadrat, others are traingle etc which I don't want. I want all the subplots to be equal sized quadrats (divide it by lines that paralel to each sides). Can you anyone guide me for this?

```
 divide <-quadrats(p.patt,3,3)
 plot(divide)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide some data and example code so we can help you. If you cannot share you actual data then use simulated or built-in dataset to illustrate your problem and what you have tried so far.

Comment: i have edited an example data frame above. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still think you have to ask a better question. You just provide 9 points in a format that I cannot easily read into R. Maybe give it a try using `dput` for you data or even better (much better) make a fully reproducible example with figures and explain in detail. I highly recommend the reprex package <https://reprex.tidyverse.org/> where you can add the argument `venue = "so"`: Simply copy the entire script into the clipboard and run `reprex(venue="so")`. Afterwards paste the result into your question here. Also a hint could be to align the data with the axes using `rotate`.

Comment: ok, I will try it. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could you break up the plot canvas into 3x3, then run each plot?

```
> par(mfrow=c(3,3))
> # run code for plot 1
> # run code for plot 2
  ...
> # run code for plot 9
```

To return back to one plot on the canvas type

```
> par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Thank you Nishan. after I divide it, I am going to apply a lots of function to each plots and return many outputs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about the `spatstat` package.

You can use the function `quantess` to divide the window into tiles of equal area. If you want the tile boundaries to be vertical lines, and you want 7 tiles, use

```
B <- quantess(Window(p.patt), "x", 7)
```

where `p.patt` is your point pattern.